# How to insert data into database with column name "default"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table in my database with next SQL code

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
`id` INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`column1` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`column2` INTEGER  NULL,
`column3` INTEGER  NULL,
`column4` INTEGER  NULL,
`default` INTEGER  NULL
);
```

And i can insert data into it with

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,'something',1,0,0,1)
```

and it works, but my question is how to enter specific values with problem that i have column with name `default` and SQL interprets that name of column like default value. Therefore i can't use inserts like

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id,column1,column2,column3,column4,default) VALUES (1,'something',1,0,0,1),
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `table` (id,column1,default) VALUES (1,'something',1),
```

or etc.

So my question is :
Is it possible to insert specific data into table with column name default and how or not? Is it possible to work this on some other databases? I'm using MySql database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a really bad column name. (And table is a really bad table name.) "defualt" is the ANSI SQL way, MySQL may use back-ticks.

Comment: @jarlh Well I wasn't the designer of the database, and i never use that kind of names for column names. I'm only trying to figure out the proper way to insert data into that kind of table.

Comment: Having inherited databases before... I feel your pain!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the column name `default` with backticks, like you have with the table name.

Answer (score 1):

do the same thing that you did on your table:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`,`column1`,`default`) VALUES (1,'something',1),
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

**default**

with

```
`default`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command and it will allow you to insert the value in the default column:

INSERT INTO `table` (id,column1,column2,column3,column4,`default`) VALUES (2,'something',1,0,0,1);

Use the same quotes over default as used for table by you.